# Bounding the probability that a random variable is maximal

Tags: st.statistics, lower-bounds, pr.probability

**Question:** Suppose we have $N$ independent random variables $X_1$, $\ldots$, $X_N$ with finite means $\mu_1 \leq \ldots \leq \mu_N$ and variances $\sigma_1^2$, $\ldots$, $\sigma_N^2$.

I am looking for distribution-free bounds on the probability that any $X_i \neq X_N$ is larger than all other $X_j$, $j \neq i$.

In other words, if for simplicity we assume the distributions of $X_i$ are continuous (such that $P(X_i = X_j) = 0$), I am looking for upper bounds for:
$$
P( X_i = \max_j X_j ) \enspace.
$$
More specifically, I want to lower bound:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i P( X_i = \max_j X_j )  \enspace.
$$
Below is a possible answer, but the bound seems quite loose and I would like to know if sharper bounds can be formulated (ideally without additional assumptions).

Please note that the variables are **not** assumed to be i.i.d..

---

**My attempt:** Recall that by assumption, $\mu_j \geq \mu_i$ whenever $j > i$. If $N=2$, we can use Chebyshev's inequality to get
$$
P(X_1 = \max_j X_j) = P(X_1 > X_2) \leq \frac{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 + (\mu_1 - \mu_2)^2} \enspace.
$$
We can use this bound for general $N \geq 2$ to arrive at
$$
P(X_i = \max_j X_j) \leq \min_{j > i} \frac{\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_j^2 + (\mu_j - \mu_i)^2} \leq \frac{\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_N^2}{\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_N^2 + (\mu_N - \mu_i)^2} \enspace.
$$
This implies, for all $i$
$$
( \mu_N - \mu_i ) P( X_i = \max_j X_j ) \leq (\mu_N - \mu_i) \frac{\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_N^2}{\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_N^2 + (\mu_N - \mu_i)^2} \leq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \sigma_i^2 + \sigma_N^2 } \enspace.
$$
This, in turn, implies
$$\tag{1}
\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i P( X_i = \max_j X_j ) \geq \mu_N - \frac{N-1}{2} \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} (\sigma_i^2 + \sigma_N^2) } \enspace.
$$
I am trying to find out whether this bound can be improved to something that does not depend linearly on $N$. For instance, does the following hold:
$$\tag{2}
\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i P( X_i = \max_j X_j ) \geq \mu_N - \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^2 } \enspace?
$$
And if not, what could be a counterexample?

Comment: It may be good to note that (2) is implied by (1) for $N = 2$ and $N = 3$, so if a counterexample for (2) exists, it would have to be for $N \geq 4$. Any thoughts, for instance for a different route to attack this problem or references in which similar problems are discussed, are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If (2) holds for a collection of random variables, does it also hold if you add a Bernoulli random variable to the collection?

Comment: @Douglas Zare : Good question, I'm not sure. Lets denote $$p_i(n)=P(X_i=\max_{j\leq n}X_j)$$ and renumber s.t. $\mu_1\geq\ldots\geq\mu_N$. Then (2) states $$\sum_i^N p_i(N)(\mu_1-\mu_i)\leq\sqrt{\sum_i^N\sigma_i^2}.$$ Suppose this holds and we add $X_{N+1}$, with $\mu_{N+1}\leq\mu_N$. Of course, $p_i(N+1)\leq p_i(N)$ for all $i\leq N$. Therefore, $$\sum_i^N p_i(N+1)(\mu_1-\mu_i) \leq p_i(N+1)(\mu_1-\mu_{N+1})+\sum_i^N p_i(N)(\mu_1-\mu_i) \leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_{N+1}^2}+\sqrt{\sum_i^N \sigma_i^2},$$ but this is not always smaller than $\sqrt{\sum_i^{N+1}\sigma_i^2}$.

Comment: Of course, this does not prove that (2) *does not* hold for general $N$, just that my inductive argument does not prove that it *does*. Furthermore, note that (1) holds for $N=2$, and in that case is stronger. So perhaps an increasing function $C(N) < 1$, $\lim_{N \to \infty} C(N) = 1$ exists for which a similar inductive argument does hold, using $C(N) \sqrt{\sum_i^N \sigma_i^2}$.

Comment: Crossposted to stats.SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30245

Comment: I don't know the policy of mathoverflow on crossposting, but I'd be happy to delete either question if that is considered the right thing to do. Please let me know either way. I'm sorry if I breached the etiquette of either site.

Comment: To avoid duplication of effort and to let more people benefit from any answers or comments, you should at least mention that you are crossposting and provide a link. Thanks to cardinal for doing so. 

Comment: @Douglas Zare : That's a good point. Sorry for failing to do so. I was of course planning on transferring interesting ideas or answers, but a direct link is of course much more straightforward. However, in the future I will refrain from crossposting altogether. In any case, I'm still very curious about any thoughts about the question in question. I've worked some more on your induction suggestion, but have not reached any satisfactory solutions: I have not been able to prove equation (2), but I have not been able to disprove it either.

Comment: I propose to take any future discussion on this question to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30245 since it was posted there first. I hope this is okay.

Comment: Since it is now over a month later and I still have not found an answer I've reposted this question to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172793/distribution-free-bounds-on-the-probability-of-maximality .